# Flutter NoSuchMethodError:class Future <dynamic> has no instance method 'call'

Tags: flutter, dynamic, future

I am getting `NoSuchMethodError:class Future <dynamic> has no instance method 'call'. Receiver:Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'Tried calling:call()` error and have no idea how to fix my code.

This is my code that made error.

```
_getFromGallery() async {
  XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    maxWidth: 1800,
    maxHeight: 1800,
  );
  cropImage(pickedFile!.path);
}

cropImage(pickedFile) async {
  File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
    sourcePath: pickedFile,
    maxWidth: 1080,
    maxHeight: 1080,
  );
  if (croppedImage != null) {
    image = croppedImage;
    Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => cropImage(pickedFile)()));
  }
}

Widget cropImage(pickedFile) {
  return FutureBuilder<File>(
      future: pickedFile,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData == null){
    } 
      return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Set Profile Images'),
  ),
  body:  Center(
    child: new Container(
        width: 250.0,
        height: 250.0,
        child: cropImage(pickedFile)),
  ),);
  });
}
```

[image: error display]

I get this image when I try to get the final cropped image. The error comes up and immediately goes back to cropping image screen.

Comment: `pickedFile` should be a future and it is not. Please check documentation of [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: hey can u explain further ?

Comment: did u find answer to the above